# ssh access between windows host and centos running in virtual box gives Access Denied

Tags: centos, ssh

I tried turning off the firewall using
`system-config-firewall` GUI.
Also, turned off SELinux.
But I am not able to connect to guest CentOS inside virtual box using windows 7 host machine. 
I am able to ping guest OS. I reinstalled sshd and also tried running it on different port (5562) but always get "Access denied" after entering correct password.

Additional details:
I have configured my guest OS with static IP 10.0.2.10.
Also, virtualbox host-only network is setup with IP address 192.168.56.1

If I try `ssh localhost` on guest OS, it works correctly.
Also, tried ssh'ing to guest OS from other machine running CentOS. It also gets permission denied error.

Also, tried running wireshark on guestOS, it does not receive any request on port 22 when host OS gives access denied error.

```
netstat -l --numeric_ports | grep 22
```

correctly shows

```
tcp  0 0 *:22 *:* LISTEN
```

sshd_config file

```
#    $OpenBSD: sshd_config,v 1.80 2008/07/02 02:24:18 djm Exp $

# This is the sshd server system-wide configuration file.  See
# sshd_config(5) for more information.

# This sshd was compiled with PATH=/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin

# The strategy used for options in the default sshd_config shipped with
# OpenSSH is to specify options with their default value where
# possible, but leave them commented.  Uncommented options change a
# default value.

Port 22
AddressFamily any
ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
ListenAddress ::

# Disable legacy (protocol version 1) support in the server for new
# installations. In future the default will change to require explicit
 # activation of protocol 1
Protocol 2

# HostKey for protocol version 1
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_key
# HostKeys for protocol version 2
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key

# Lifetime and size of ephemeral version 1 server key
#KeyRegenerationInterval 1h
#ServerKeyBits 1024

# Logging
# obsoletes QuietMode and FascistLogging
#SyslogFacility AUTH
SyslogFacility AUTHPRIV
 #LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:

#LoginGraceTime 2m
#PermitRootLogin yes
#StrictModes yes
#MaxAuthTries 6
#MaxSessions 10

#RSAAuthentication yes
#PubkeyAuthentication yes
#AuthorizedKeysFile    .ssh/authorized_keys
 #AuthorizedKeysCommand none
#AuthorizedKeysCommandRunAs nobody

# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
#RhostsRSAAuthentication no
# similar for protocol version 2
#HostbasedAuthentication no
 # Change to yes if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for
# RhostsRSAAuthentication and HostbasedAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts no
# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
#IgnoreRhosts yes

# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
#PasswordAuthentication yes
#PermitEmptyPasswords no
PasswordAuthentication yes

# Change to no to disable s/key passwords
#ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes
 ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes
#KerberosGetAFSToken no
#KerberosUseKuserok yes

# GSSAPI options
 GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPIAuthentication yes
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes
GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes
#GSSAPIStrictAcceptorCheck yes
#GSSAPIKeyExchange no

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing, 
 # and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will 
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
 # the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
 #UsePAM no
UsePAM yes

# Accept locale-related environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_CTYPE LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME LC_COLLATE LC_MONETARY LC_MESSAGES
AcceptEnv LC_PAPER LC_NAME LC_ADDRESS LC_TELEPHONE LC_MEASUREMENT
 AcceptEnv LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_ALL LANGUAGE
AcceptEnv XMODIFIERS

#AllowAgentForwarding yes
#AllowTcpForwarding yes
#GatewayPorts no
#X11Forwarding no
X11Forwarding yes
#X11DisplayOffset 10
#X11UseLocalhost yes
 #PrintMotd yes
#PrintLastLog yes
#TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no
#UsePrivilegeSeparation yes
#PermitUserEnvironment no
#Compression delayed
#ClientAliveInterval 0
#ClientAliveCountMax 3
#ShowPatchLevel no
 #UseDNS yes
#PidFile /var/run/sshd.pid
#MaxStartups 10
#PermitTunnel no
#ChrootDirectory none

# no default banner path
#Banner none

# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem    sftp    /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server

# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#    X11Forwarding no
#    AllowTcpForwarding no
#    ForceCommand cvs server
```

Comment: What username are you using ? Can you post your SSHD config file here ?

Comment: @Stephane added sshd_config. Tried both "GSSAPIAuthentication yes" & no.

Comment: Your Guest OS and HOSt OS are in different subnet thats why you are not able to ping or do ssh to your guest OS from host OS.

Comment: @AbhishekAmralkar but I am able to ping...

Answer (score 1):

You have several options in configuring your network adapter on virtualbox machine:
The **default** is **NAT**, so if you do nothing then you just need to do PORT FORWARD in network option tab (Network--->Adapter--->Advanced). Please take a look at [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9537751/virtualbox-port-forward-from-guest-to-host)

Answer (score 0):

In virtual box, one needs to enable Adapter 2 attached to Host-only adapter and use the IP address provided by second adapter (eth1) to ssh connect.

Explained in detail in below link:
http://wiredrevolution.com/virtualbox/setup-ssh-access-between-virtualbox-host-and-guest-vms

Adapter 1 (Attached To: NAT) & eth0 should be left as it is for internet. I was incorrectly trying to access both internet and ssh through eth0.